# How to filter out positional data based on distance from a known reference trajectory?

Tags: python, pandas, gps, data-science, data-cleaning

I have a 87288-point dataset that I need to filter. The filtering fields for the dataset are a X position and a Y position, as latitude and longitude. Plotted the data looks like this:

[image: Y vs X scatter plot]

The problem is , I only need data along a certain path, which is known in advance.  Something like this:

[image]

I already know how to filter data in a Pandas DF, but given the path is not linear, I need an effective strategy to clear out all the noisy data with a certain degree of precision (since the dataset is so large, manually picking the points is not an option).

Here is some sample data.The only important columns are Latitude and Longitude, Y and X respectively.

```
Sesion,Tiempo,Latitud,Longitud,PM2.5,Modo,Hora,DiaSemana
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-01 09:48:17.625,3.3659550000000005,-76.5288288,13.0,OUTDOOR,AM,1
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:03.555,3.3661757000000003,-76.5289441,12.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:04.596,3.3661757000000003,-76.5289441,11.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:05.572,3.3661767,-76.5289375,11.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:06.614,3.3661790999999996,-76.5289188,11.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:07.581,3.3661814,-76.5289024,11.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:08.588,3.3661847999999996,-76.52889820000001,11.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:09.570,3.3661922,-76.52890450000001,11.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:10.579,3.3661922,-76.52890450000001,11.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:11.577,3.3662135,-76.52893370000001,12.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:12.611,3.3662227999999996,-76.5289516,12.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:13.561,3.3662227999999996,-76.5289516,11.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:14.631,3.3662346,-76.5289927,11.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:15.554,3.3662421,-76.52901440000001,10.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:16.623,3.3662523999999996,-76.5290363,10.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:17.593,3.3662523999999996,-76.5290363,10.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:18.617,3.3662523999999996,-76.5290363,10.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:19.608,3.3662523999999996,-76.5290363,10.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:20.605,3.3662523999999996,-76.5290363,10.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:21.594,3.3662523999999996,-76.5290363,10.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:22.608,3.3662523999999996,-76.5290363,10.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:23.620,3.3662523999999996,-76.5290363,10.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:24.611,3.3662523999999996,-76.5290363,10.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:25.622,3.3662523999999996,-76.5290363,10.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:26.590,3.3662523999999996,-76.5290363,10.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:27.619,3.3662523999999996,-76.5290363,10.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:28.595,3.3662523999999996,-76.5290363,10.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:29.628,3.3662523999999996,-76.5290363,10.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
M-O-AM-07OCT19-DMR,2019-10-07 08:18:30.621,3.3662523999999996,-76.5290363,10.0,OUTDOOR,AM,0
```

I have tried of handpicking a few points inside the route, and filtering the rest using a fixed min distance, something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from cycler import cycler
import numpy as np
from salem import get_demo_file, DataLevels, GoogleVisibleMap, Map
import geopy.distance

def get_dist(coords_1 , coords_2):
    return geopy.distance.distance(coords_1, coords_2).meters

dists=[
    (-76.5297163,3.3665631),
    (-76.5307019,3.3656924),
    (-76.5314718,3.3646900),
    (-76.5319956,3.3638394),
    (-76.5316622,3.3621781),
    (-76.5311999,3.3611796),
    (-76.5308636,3.3599338),
    (-76.5306335,3.3585191),
    (-76.5304758,3.3577502),
    (-76.5303957,3.3561101),
    (-76.5302998,3.3543178),
    (-76.5302220,3.3531897),
    (-76.5302369,3.3515283),
    (-76.5303363,3.3502667),
    (-76.5305351,3.3485951),
    (-76.5306779,3.3475220),
    (-76.5308545,3.3456382),
    (-76.5307738,3.3446934),
    (-76.530618,3.3430422)
]
df = pd.read_csv('movil.csv')


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index%1000 ==0:
        print(index)
    mind=None
    for i in dists:
        if mind:
            d=get_dist((row['Latitud'],row['Longitud']),(i[1],i[0]))
            if d<mind:
                mind=d
        else:
            mind=get_dist((row['Latitud'],row['Longitud']),(i[1],i[0]))
    if mind>125:
        df.drop(index, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Using these approach I managed to get some cleaning, but I feel a lot of useful data is getting filtered.

[image]

Comment: Is the red path known in advance, or are you trying to infer the "main" path from the frequency/density of data points there?

Comment: Hi, the red path is known in advance. @NicholasM

Comment: Can you include some sample data in the question, as well as the code you have written so far to solve this?  It is asking a lot of other SO users to generate some realistic sample data in order to answer the question.

Comment: I have added some sample data and my current approach to solve the issue. Hope it helps. @NicholasM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with some sample data.  Note that latitude and longitude are recorded in *degrees* for generation and plotting, but in *radians* for computation.

```
import numpy
import pandas

def add_radians(df):
    return df.assign(**{colname.rstrip("_deg"): numpy.radians(col) for colname, col in df.iteritems()})

n_ref = 26
ref_traj = pandas.DataFrame({"lat_deg": -76 + numpy.linspace(-1, 1, n_ref),
                             "lon_deg":   3 + numpy.linspace(-1, 1, n_ref)**2,
                            }).pipe(add_radians)

n = 500
traj = pandas.DataFrame({"lat_deg": -76 + numpy.cumsum(numpy.random.choice([-1, 1], size=n) * 0.05),
                         "lon_deg":   3 + numpy.cumsum(numpy.random.choice([-1, 1], size=n) * 0.05),
                        }).pipe(add_radians)

ax = traj.plot.scatter(x="lat_deg", y="lon_deg")
ax = ref_traj.plot.scatter(x="lat_deg", y="lon_deg", color="red", ax=ax)
```

[image: Empirical and reference trajectories]

Next, we can define a vectorized function returning the distance between two points.  This should work for 1- or 2-dimensional arrays.

```
def distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    # TODO: check that shape of lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 are all compatible.
    R = 6371  # Radius of Earth in kilometers

    # TODO: check this distance calculation

    def hav(theta):
        return numpy.sin(theta)**2

    d_lat = lat2 - lat1
    d_lon = lon2 - lon1
    a = hav(d_lat / 2) + numpy.cos(lat1) * numpy.cos(lat2) * hav(d_lon / 2)
    return 2 * R * numpy.sqrt(a)
```

Then, we can attempt to find the *minimum* distance from each trajectory point to *any* reference trajectory point.  This is computationally expensive, at `O(N*M)`, but we can vectorize it by broadcasting the reference points and trajectory points into 2-D arrays.

```
def min_distance(ref_lat, ref_lon, lat, lon):
    shape = (numpy.shape(lat)[0], numpy.shape(ref_lat)[0])

    def broadcasted(a):
        return numpy.broadcast_to(a, shape=shape)

    d = distance(lat1=broadcasted(ref_lat), 
                 lon1=broadcasted(ref_lon), 
                 lat2=broadcasted(lat[:, numpy.newaxis]),
                 lon2=broadcasted(lon[:, numpy.newaxis]))
    return numpy.amin(d, axis=-1)
```

Finally, we can choose a tolerance and filter points that have a minimum distance less than the tolerance.

```
d = min_distance(ref_traj['lat'], ref_traj['lon'], traj['lat'], traj['lon'])
tolerance = 10  # in kilometers
near_ref = d < tolerance
```

Finally, we can use the boolean `near_ref` mask to filter the `traj` dataframe:

```
ax = ref_traj.plot.scatter(x="lat_deg", y="lon_deg", color="red")
traj[near_ref].plot.scatter(x="lat_deg", y="lon_deg", color="blue", ax=ax)
traj[~near_ref].plot.scatter(x="lat_deg", y="lon_deg", color="gray", ax=ax)
```

[image: Empirical trajectories, filtered by minimum distance to reference]